# JavaScript windows.print() callback - Determining when a print job completes

Tags: javascript, firefox, printing

**Question**: Is it possible to add a callback to the `windows.print()` function? I realize there isn't a native solution, but I was wondering if there is some sort of library that accomplishes this. Note - I have access to the computers if I need to install something.

**Background**: I have implemented a web POS solution that runs on Firefox (v44-46). For some orders, I need to print 2 receipts on an Epson TM-T88V printer.

**Problem**: If the second `windows.print()` method executes while the first receipt is still printing, Firefox prompts "Some printing functionality is not available".

**Possible Solution**: I can increase the delay between print calls. However, this isn't very robust since some orders can be quite lengthy, whereas others are not. This solution might not work for some cases, and would simply slow down others.

Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to listen for the [`afterprint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint) event

```
window.addEventListener('afterprint', e => console.log('Ready for next print job'));
```

Please note that this has low cross-browser support (*FireFox 6+, IE*)

---

The [**MDN page**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint#See_also) also tells us that something similar can be achieved in webkit based browsers by adding a listener on `matchMedia('print')`, so you could shim it by writing something like the following for those browsers

```
window.matchMedia('print').addListener(mql => {
    if (!mql.matches) {
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('afterprint'));
    }
});
```

This should work in e.g. *Google Chrome*

Comment: Unfortunately, this callback fires once the user accepts the print job, rather than when the print job finishes. Although, I don't think there is an easy way to achieve this using javascript. Going to accept this answer since it might be sufficient for others.