# After cancel or save print dialog the current window was hung

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, dom-events, freeze

I create big HTML page (4 MB) and then call `window.print()`. I want to run some JavaScript code after user close the print dialog. But `afterprint` event called too late (after 10-20 sec) and page hanging.
Dom contains about 80 `SVG` elements created by [highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/) and the size of created HTML file is about 4 MB.

```
// create html page dynamically
// run some code before print
window.onafterprint = function() {
    // run some code after print
}
window.print();
```

Comment: Sounds a bit strange. I suspect, that you are doing some complicated calculations. Could you try to explain me more precisely what you're doing step by step? I tried to reproduce the issue, but without any effect similar to mentioned above. Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/u0d9Lmtw/

Comment: I create some pages that contains 4 chart, one canvas and three tables and draw something on each canvas and fills tables with data and and call `highchart` with some data to draw charts... Then call `window.peint()` and everything is OK, but after close print dialog, the page hanging and `afterprint` event called too late

Comment: When I reduce canvas's size, the delay time will be reduced. But it is not my best solution.

Comment: I understand the problem, but it's hard to find the solution without debugging it. Could you try to prepare a minimal working example and provide me with it?

Comment: Duplicate.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090065/javascript-windows-print-callback-determining-when-a-print-job-completes